# VB.NET (ASPX) Application Works in Visual Studio but Not in IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, iis

We have a legacy VB.NET (ASPX) application that we need to migrate to a new server after the old server crashed, unfortunately we keep running into a weird Oracle issue (possibly caused by a 32bit/64bit conflict issue).  Here is the error message we receive on the new server when running under IIS 7.5:

```
The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
```

However, when running the exact same application on the exact same server in Visual Studio 2010, the application works without any issues.

Some of the things I've tried .... changing the Oracle.DataAccess.dll file from the current 32bit to 64bit file, same results (doesn't work in IIS, works in Visual Studio); deploying the application as a package or as a website (same result).

Comment: Make sure you've selected the proper framework version for the application in IIS.

Comment: Have you tried running in a 32-bit app pool (app pool advanced settings, Enable 32-Bit Applications = True)?

Comment: Look carefully at the version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` that came with your application and the one that is located in `home\...\odp.net\bin`. I bet - versions are not matching. If this is the case - you using wrong client for your application. If the problem was x64 vs x86 - you would get "program in wrong format" message

Answer (score 0):

I always got stuck on this kind of migration from 32bit to 64bit problem in Windows Server and IIS.

First, you need to know that Visual Studio is 32bit-based. Although you use a 64-bit Oracle Client in 64-bit server, you will definitely fail. So the first thing to accomplish your connection is to use a 32-bit Oracle Client.

Now that you have installed your 32-bit Oracle Client, when you deploy your Web Application in your Server you will find that IIS can't connect to Oracle due to this problem:

```
The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
```

Because IIS is running into a 64-bit server, it won't run propperly. So, you must set your pool application to allow 32-bit application by clicking on Advance Settings and setting to True the 'Enable 32-bit Applications' option.

[image: Application Pool - Advanced Settings]